# What Intents does the Facebook Android app support

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-like, apk

As far as I know, the [Facebook app for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) only supports a basic intent.

Does anyone know of an authoritative list of intents for facebook? It would be nice if you could just have a *like* intent.

Comment: no facebook app is garbage it doesn't even properly support the ACTION_SEND intent

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk - at least some programmatic ways.

Comment: @Sebastian Roth. Thats just SDK. Though if you look into it, you will find that it supports ACTION_SEND. I don't but it still gives error many of the times.

Answer (score 16):

Obtain the apk either:

- With the Backup function of [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en). Copy the backed up apk (see /sdcard/backups/apps/) to your PC.
  OR
- With adb: Find out the apk path using `adb shell pm path com.facebook.katana`. Pull the apk from that path with e.g. `adb pull /data/app/com.facebook.katana-1.apk`

Use [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to extract the manifest file from the Facebook.apk:

> apktool.bat d Facebook.apk fbExtracted

Search for `<intent-filter>` tags inside the extracted AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="11090" android:versionName="1.8.4" package="com.facebook.katana"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" />
    <permission android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.facebook.katana.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.facebook.katana.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon_katana" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FacebookApplication">
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.UserStatusesProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.UserStatusesProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.UserValuesProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.UserValuesProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.KeyValueProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.KeyValueProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.EventsProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.EventsProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.ConnectionsProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.ConnectionsProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.PagesProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PagesProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.LoggingProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.LoggingProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.PhotosProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PhotosProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.MailboxProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.MailboxProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.NotificationsProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.NotificationsProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.ChatHistoryProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.ChatHistoryProvider" />
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.katana.provider.CacheProvider" android:permission="com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS" android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.CacheProvider" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.service.FacebookService" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.service.BackgroundDetectionService" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.service.BackgroundRequestService" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.service.UploadManager" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.RemoveRawContactsService" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.c2dm.PushReceiver" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.FacebookDark" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.NotificationsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.AlbumsActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.BugReporter" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.CreateEditAlbumActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.PhotosActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.FacebookDark" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.ViewPhotoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.ViewVideoActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.PhotoFeedbackActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.stream.StreamActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.faceweb.FacewebChromeActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.feedback.FeedbackActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.events.EventsActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.events.EventBirthdaysActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.events.EventDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.events.EventGuestsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.CropImageActivity" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.events.EventEditActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:label="@string/home_nearby" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.FriendCheckinsActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.AddPlaceActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.PlacesNearbyActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.PlacesOptInActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.StubPlacesActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.chat.BuddyListActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.chat.ChatConversationActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.ProfileTabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.profile" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.UserInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.PageInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.places.PlacesInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/home_settings" android:name="com.facebook.katana.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.UploadPhotoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.media.UploadVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" android:label="@string/facebook_status" android:name="com.facebook.katana.WidgetActivity" android:process="com.facebook.widget.affinity" android:taskAffinity="com.facebook.widget.affinity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="@string/login_about" android:name="com.facebook.katana.HtmlAboutActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.view.FacebookWebViewActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.messages.MailboxTabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.messages.MailboxThreadsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.messages.MailboxMessagesActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.messages.MessageComposeActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.WhiteText" android:name="com.facebook.katana.UsersTabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.WhiteText" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FriendsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.RequestsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.PageSearchResultsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.WhiteText" android:name="com.facebook.katana.PickFriendsActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.SyncContactsSetupActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.SyncContactsChangeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.katana.IntentUriHandler">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="facebook" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="fb" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth" android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROXYAUTH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.profilelist.TaggedUsersActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.WhiteText" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.profilelist.FriendMultiSelectorActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.profilelist.GroupListActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.profilelist.GroupMemberListActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.ComposerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FeedComposerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <receiver android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FacebookWidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FacebookAccountReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.katana.service.method.ApiLogging" />
        <receiver android:name="com.facebook.katana.c2dm.PushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
                <category android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.facebook.c2dm.send.intent.RETRY" />
                <category android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.katana.binding.ChatHibernateKeepalive" />
        <receiver android:name="com.facebook.katana.binding.UploadManagerConnectivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.platform.FacebookAuthenticationService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.platform.TokenRefreshService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" />
        <service android:name="com.facebook.katana.platform.FacebookSyncAdapterService" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE" android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
        </service>
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.DialogNoTitle" android:name="com.facebook.katana.PasswordDialogActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.katana.LoginNotificationActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.findfriends.LegalDisclaimerActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.Facebook" android:name="com.facebook.katana.activity.findfriends.FindFriendsActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity-alias android:name="com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity" android:exported="true" android:targetActivity="com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you.. I've been looking for this.